# How to see progress of general ledger batch posting

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Is there a way in Dynamics AX 2012 R2, or using a SQL query, to see the progress of a general ledger batch posting?  Not looking for a way to add code for the user to see it, but a way for a system admin, for example, to see if it is progressing.  ~300,000 lines running for >24 hours and I'd like to have some assurance it is moving along.

Answer (score 2):

This blog post by Dilip seems to be what you need:

http://daxdilip.blogspot.com/2014/02/tip-dynamics-ax-batch-execution-and.html

Basically you can use `NOLOCK` in SQL to query the uncommitted data.  Combine that with querying committed data and you should be able to write a query to get the progress you need.